# Combining ListView and DetailView

Tags: python, django

I need your help, please. I need to combine a ListView and a DetailView in a single template. I have list items appearing on the left and so I want when someone clicks one of the list items, the details should show on the left.

this is what I want to achieve:

## views.py

```
class RequestDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Request
    fields = ['content', 'author_group', 'assign_to', 'ref_code']
    template_name = 'request/request_detail.html'



class in_requests(ListView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       context = {
        'incoming': Request.objects.filter(assign_to=request.user.profile.department).filter(status='Pending')
           }
        return render(request, 'request/incoming.html', context)
```

Comment: Do you want to achive this by reloading the whole page (i.e. the list on the left and the details on the right) when a user clicks on an item or do you just want load the details on user click? The second approach would require javascript

Comment: Hi @Chris thanks for your response. I would like to load the details on user click. How can I achieve it by JavaScript?

Comment: In your template you need to send an ajax request to your ```DetailView``` when the user clicks on an item. Your ```DetailView``` should return a Json reponse containing the detail data which you then can put into the required position on your page. There are a number of SO posts explaining how you can do this. If you get stuck and need a more specific answer, please post your models and you html templates.